# Configure Android as proxy server

Tags: networking, proxy

Hi am trying to convert my mobile device as proxy server, I searched net but cant find proper solution.

What I am trying to do :

Setup proxy server on android and use that mobile IP/Proxy IP address in my PC browser as proxy.

In Pc we can use Squid Proxy for this purpose I am searching similar framework in Android/Mobile to convert my mobile into proxy server

Comment: See: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/138519/using-your-android-phone-as-a-proxy-server

Comment: Hi,Thanks for suggestion unfortunately that is not working for me. is there any document so that I can follow thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try [SandroProxy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sandroproxy), a free app developed by XDA Developers member SandroBSupp.

> It can act as pass-through proxy, traffic is not stored, ssl tunnel
>   remains the same to server.
>
> SandroProxy doesn’t require root. All you need to do is to hit the
>   Play button and the app will serve as an SSL MITM proxy (Secure Socket
>   Layer Man-In- the -Middle-proxy). Your HTTP/HTTPS requests will be
>   redirected through a web server, making your sent and received data
>   invisible and, thus, protected.

You can access transparent proxy, a network layer proxy which, in turn, redirects the traffic needed by your phone for proxy identification. The only traffic that this proxy modifies are those which are absolutely necessary for proxy identification and authorization.

*Uses proxy on localhost:8008*

Haven't used it but it looks promising for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, I installed that app., proxy listening on 127.0.0.1:8008, If I check my IP in mobile browser "what is my ip" I am getting 92.20.xx.x . Now If I try to set that in my PC Firefox in network settings  92.20.xx.x:8008  It is not routing via that proxy. Please explain what I am doing wrong