# Trying and failing to use phone mobile data as proxy

Tags: networking, proxy

I tried following this: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/196779/327770

- I connected my android phone, a Samsung 8 with Roger's sim card to my computer
- Bridged with adb
- Port forwarded 6400 on my computer to 8080 on the phone
- Started a proxy server with servers ultimate
- Visited 127.0.0.1:6400, it works! I was excited!
- But then I try to use 127.0.0.1:6400 as a proxy gateway, it doesn't work, I don't know why, or what else to do.

Any help?

Comment: What proxy do you use on the phone and how is the proxy started? Is there a reason why you don't use the standard USB tethering?

Comment: Have you tried setting proxy settings with a different browser Ex: try Firefox if you already have tried Chrome and vice versa.

Comment: @Robert I'm not using a proxy on my phone, I'm using the mobile data, I'd like a different application to use the IP resulting from my mobile data, that's why I don't just do standard USB tethering or hotspot.

Comment: @M.Abdelhafid Yes, I tried it on both Chrome and Firefox, I get ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES, but when I visit the port on my browser, I'm able to access the files on the device, so I think the portforwarding works fine, but trying to send data out isn't working, I think.

Comment: In your question you wrote that you are using a proxy on your phone that runs on port 8080 - and now you say you don't use a proxy. And regarding the IP: It does not matter you you use a proxy on the phone or USB tethering (which uses NAT), you only get one IP address from your network provider, hence all request end up using the same IP address: The one from your phone.

Comment: @Robert Sorry if I wasn't clear, I started a proxy server on port 8080, my goal is to send traffic from port 6400 on my computer, through port 8080 on my phone, to the internet. I have a wifi connection on my computer, it has a different IP from the mobile connection on my phone, i'd like to use the mobile connection on my phone - on my computer. I hope that clarifies some things.

Comment: If you want to use your mobile connection on your PC just use USB tethering. If you don't believe me do it and open the page https://www.whatsmyip.org/ on both mobile and PC. They will show the same IP address.