# Android phone as 4G proxy server

Tags: proxy, 4g

I am trying to turn my old phone (Xiaomi Mi 5) into a 4G proxy server which I can use with different apps for scraping data, etc. I have been searching on how to set it up and I found some articles, but they are not very clear. I am really a newbie and I have no idea how to set it up. I have bought 2 Android apps: Proxy Server Pro and Servers Ultimate Pro having trouble configuring it.

These are the steps I have followed on Servers Ultimate Pro:

- Add a proxy server

  - In the General tab, I didn't touch anything
  - In the Rules tab, added a new rule

    - HOST CONTAINS: I put my public IP address which I found at https://myip.com
    - REPLY WITH THIS IP: 127.0.0.1 Port: 1080

Now, when I try to test it I, get no connection.

Comment: You can run `tinyproxy` from commandline. See my answer to [using your android phone as a proxy server](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217831/218526)

Comment: unfortunately nope i have already checked that question. Basically it explains how to setup a proxy server via wifi, but i need it with mobile data. The thing is that when i use another app called Allproxy which is a fremium app it works it gives me the protocol://user:pass@host:port and it works it means that the ports from my ISP are opened and not blocked. But this app steals your data so i have heard and i don´t want to risk. I want to set it up myself via Servers Ultimate pro or Proxy Server pro. About your answer in that post i checked it but i am unable to code at all.

Comment: I still don't see the point in running a proxy on a mobile network only device. Are there any sites or resources that are only accessible from within the network of your cellphone provider?

Comment: @Robert because i manage social media and buying a mobile proxy costs way too much than turning my old device with a basic data plan into a proxy..

Comment: @MarianPepa I have never had a carrier plan which provides a public IP address, but I've been using a VPN VPS to get a static public IP when using mobile data. And `tinyproxy` always worked perfectly. It's free, open-source and very lightweight. Do consider it if you want a long term solution. Setting it up isn't difficult if you get basic familiarity with *NIX shell usage.

Comment: @IrfanLatif In Germany T-Mobile AFAIK has some older business plans with public IP. Also data plans dedicated for IoT may have a public IP, of course only by large old corporations which get their (large) IP range early in the Internet history so that they now still have enough IPv4 addresses.

Comment: but really it shouldn’t be so complicated after all. I am missing something i know it. I am a total newbie, can i post some screenshots to show you guys how did i configure it ?

Comment: @IrfanLatif i am definitely going to give it a try but in this case i would need a vps right? (which would be another extra monthly cost for me)

Comment: You don't need VPS if you have already a public IP. If you don't have, you cannot access the proxy server from internet whatever tool or app you use on Android to run the proxy.

Comment: @IrfanLatif my public ips are constantly rotating and previously with the apps i mentioned above i have been trying to set up also a Dynamic DNS updater (no-ip) how do i set this up with tinyproxy in my phone?